# Converting a bitmap to a Uri to be stored in an SQL database

Tags: bitmap, uri

I have a contacts app and when I call the camera on the device it saves the image as a bitmap. However i need it to be a URI because 
thats what gets saved in the SQL database for the contact. When I make a call to the gallery or photo app those get pulled in as uri's right away and will be saved to the SQL database, but the immediate camera pictures don't. Please help, I'm really confused, heres my code

```
 protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            if (requestCode == 20) {
                Bitmap thumbnail = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
                ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new    ByteArrayOutputStream();
                thumbnail.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, bytes);

                File destination = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),
                        System.currentTimeMillis() + ".jpg");

                FileOutputStream fo;
                try {
                    destination.createNewFile();
                    fo = new FileOutputStream(destination);
                    fo.write(bytes.toByteArray());
               enter code here     fo.close();
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                contactImageImgView.setImageURI(Uri.parse(String.valueOf(thumbnail)));
```

I've tried several different thing none of which work.

Comment: Please clarity *but the immediate camera pictures don't*. Any error? Where? Of which type?

Comment: Also which platform are you working on? Which language?

Comment: Its Java in android studio. The error is the camera launches but the picture that is taken doesnt save to the contact's image because those images are stored as Uri's